# How do I configure nginx for WordPress REST API in sub-folder?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, nginx-config

I am trying to set up multiple Wordpress sites in sub-folders under our domain (ie not multi-site), but I have difficulty configuring the REST API endpoints. For example, this endpoint works fine:

```
https://example.com/site1/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts
```

But this endpoint gives a 404:

```
https://example.com/site1/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

I have tried to rewrite the failing url to the working url with these rules in my nginx configuration:

```
location /site1/wp-json {
    rewrite ^/site1/wp-json(.*)$ /site1/?rest_route=$1;
}

location /site1/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

I can't see any special handling of wp-json in the [WordPress docs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/) or the [nginx wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/). What am I missing here? The permalinks for the site is set to `Numeric` (https://example.com/site1/archives/123) if that might play a role.

### Update

Gist of the redacted [full config file](https://gist.github.com/JannieT/171c88171c01c6c8d17932a1027692d7) and the config syntax lints okay:

```
nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t
```

> nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Can you show the full config?

Comment: I've seen the rewrite line with the last flag at the end. Maybe that is what is missing?

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani I have just tried with adding last and also rearranging the order of the two rewrite rules, but it didn't fix the 404

Comment: @JannieTheunissen, I would like to see the full config to be able to comment on something. Currently, just these two lines don't help me

Comment: A gist of the full config coming up. I just need to redact a bunch of things in there

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added the full config

Comment: Do you need both rewrite rules?  Why not just the location /site1/.  That should set the pretty permalinks for the whole install, including the wp-json endpoints, no?  As opposed to trying to rewrite the root, and a subdirectory.

Comment: @DubVader I agree that logically we shouldn't need both, but I added the specific wp-json one because that route fails. Maybe it is caused by some of the other multi-site rules in the config? I just don't know enough nginx to spot it.

Comment: @JannieTheunissen [debug rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/333048/best-way-to-debug-nginx-config-file) may help

Comment: @JannieTheunissen writing the pretty permalinks should effect the entire install, including the endpoints.  That is why your other endpoint call works with the query string, which is the default.  I also noticed you have an "$is_args$args" as part of it.  This could be fine, but if you just tried "?$args" instead.

Comment: @JannieTheunissen, lets discuss this over the gist so commenting code is easier

Comment: @JannieTheunissen did you ever get it to work? Running into the same issue. Odd thing is that I was able to get custom routes working with a couple of different methods: `rewrite ^/wordpress/wp-json/(.*?)$ /wordpress/index.php?rest_route=/$1 last;` and/or `try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args /wordpress/index.php?q=$uri&$args;`  But default routes like `wp-json/wp/v2/pages` return an empty array.

Answer (score 5):

I just hit this too, in WP 5.7.  Without pretty permalinks, ie with the "*Plain*" option like `?p=123`, my nginx WP installation uses requests like:

> /index.php?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/&who=authors...

And these all work fine.

However if I enable pretty permalinks, eg "*Post name*", `/sample-post/`, it starts making requests like:

> /wp-json/wp/v2/users/?who=authors...

And these all return a 404.  For example, editing or publishing posts fails, and browser devtools shows a string of 404s in this format.

But now we know the pattern that works, a solution is clear - we just need to map the not-working format to the working format:

```
# Resolves WP Gutenberg 404 issue
location /wp-json {
    rewrite ^/wp-json(.*)$ /index.php?rest_route=$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve it like this:

```
location /wordpress/ {
  rewrite ^/wordpress/wp-json/(.*?)$ /wordpress/index.php?rest_route=/$1 last;
}
```

Comment: I somehow missed your answer before posting mine - this works for me, +1. I'm leaving my answer as I go into more detail about how/why it works, which might be useful to others.  I also think a `location` that more specifically targets just the URIs we want to modify would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the rewrite directive should be written as shown below:

```
server {
    location /site1/wp-json
        {
            rewrite ^(/site1/wp-json.*)$ /site1/?rest_route=$1 last;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Faham. I tried your solution, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please posts the results by running `nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t` in your terminal.

Comment: @JannieTheunissen there should be a site-enabled folder in your /etc/nginx can you check if there is any configuration file there? and if so, add the configurations over in that file.

Comment: There is two included configurations which I have merged into the gist to get the whole picture

Comment: I know this is a very stupid question but after pondering for hours on your configuration file I am only left with the dumbest question of all. What is your website permalink setting?

Comment: Thanks for your effort Faham. The permalink setting is `Numeric` (see question)

Comment: I thought so, its often the simplest of the things. Can you change your permalink to postname and check again.

Comment: I tried setting permalinks to postname and I still have the same problem. I saw numerous answers on SO where they suggest setting the permalinks to anything other than the default to resolve getting 404 on WordPress ajax calls

Comment: Numeric permalink are never going to work as the rewrite will only work if pretty permalink are on.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way **if your website pages in the subfolder is already working**, just add **index.php** to the url:

```
https://site1.com/site2/index.php/wp-json/
```

If your website pages still doesn't work in the subfolder, add this code to nginx/sites-available/website.conf file too:

```
location /site2 {
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /site2/$2 break;
        rewrite ^/site2/(.*)$ /site2/index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```